# Utilizing different dependencies, depending on instantiated class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Here is the case:

1. I have 2 SDK library provided by 2 different companies (dlls)
2. Both used the same third party dll as dependencies for these SDK
3. The versions of the dlls used by each of the companies is different
4. My code needs to instantiate one of the dlls, depending on the user input. There will never be a need to instantiate both in the same run.
5. There is no way to ask the companies to use the same version of the third party dll.

Right now, I am removing the dependency and compiling the code 2 different times. And forcing the user to choose at installation time which one will be used.

I wanted to check if it possible:

1. (best)to dynamic load the dependency on run time - depending on the instantiated class.
   or if not possible:
2. include a compile time directive to choose de correct dependencies

Notice that the problematic dll is a 2nd level dependency needed by the 1st level dependency. So I would probably need to dynamic load both (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

If shared third party dll is strongly signed and later version is compatible with earlier one you can use [assembly redirect policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .config file to always use latest version.

I.e. works fine with Json.Net libraries (strongly signed, later versions can be used instead of with earlier once)

Sample from the article:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="someAssembly" publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```